# Условие попадания точки в сектор круга

Tags: c#, математика, геометрия

Пишу программу на c#, помогите с математикой. 
У нас есть координаты вектора, который берет начало из точки (0;0) и координаты точки на плоскости. Вектор мы вращаем на 35 градусов влево и на 35 градусов вправо относительно исходного положения. Получается 2 вектора, угол между которыми 70 градусов(сектор круга). Нужно определить, попадает ли точка, лежащая на плоскости в этот сектор.
НЕ путать сегмент и сектор!

Comment: А в чем трудности? Вариант в лоб: по расстоянию до точки определяем попадает ли она в круг или нет. Если попадает, то по координатам точки находим угол между осью абсцисс и прямой, проходящей через точку и начало круга. Далее сравниваем этот угол с углами, полученными от вращения вашего вектора.

Comment: Задача на перевод в полярные координаты. Перведите координаты точки из декартовых координат в полярные (гугл вам в помощь), после чего ответ на вопрос задачи становится тривиальным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задача на самом деле интересна тем, что не так просто определить, лежит ли луч между двумя другими лучами. Если вы будете сравнивать значение полярного угла, вам придётся корректно обработать случай, когда «разрез» множества значений угла лежит между вашими векторами. Пример: если ваши лежат в промежутке (-180, 180], то луч 180 лежит между лучами 179 и -179.

Если лучи у нас заданы углами углами, нам понадобится операция *нормализации* угла: приведению угла в нужный промежуток.

```
double mod(double n, double d)
{
    if (d <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("denominator is negative");
    double remainder = n % d;
    return (remainder >= 0) ? remainder : (remainder + d);
}

// return value is the same as =angle=, but in interval [basis, basis + 2*pi)
double normalize(double angle, double basis)
{
    var diff = mod(angle - basis, 2 * Math.PI);
    // diff is in [0, 2pi)
    return basis + diff;
}
```

Теперь, пусть данные лучи заданы углами α₁ и α₂, а искомый луч — углом β. Что означает, что луч лежит между данными лучами? Ведь два луча задают *два* угла. Есть два возможных ответа:

1. β лежит внутри того из углов, который меньше π.

   Получаем код:

   ```
   bool isWithinSmallerAngle(double a1, double a2, double b)
   {
       var spread = normalize(a2 - a1, 0);
       if (spread <= Math.PI)
       {
           var diffTo1 = normalize(b - a1, 0);
           return diffTo1 > 0 && diffTo1 < spread;
       }
       else
       {
           spread = 2 * Math.PI - spread;
           var diffTo2 = normalize(b - a2, 0);
           return diffTo2 > 0 && diffTo2 < spread;
       }
   }
   ```
2. β лежит внутри угла, считаемого в направлении увеличения от α₁ к α₂.

   Получаем код:

   ```
   bool isWithinDirectedAngle(double a1, double a2, double b)
   {
       var spread = normalize(a2 - a1, 0);
       var diffTo1 = normalize(b - a1, 0);
       return diffTo1 > 0 && diffTo1 < spread;
   }
   ```

---

Операция перевода в полярные координаты достаточно тяжеловесна (необходимо использовать функцию `atan2`), так что хотелось бы по возможности её избежать. Если нам лучи заданы как сонаправленные векторы, то можно всё вычислить следующим образом. Нам понадобится операция «узнать, в одной ли полуплоскости данные вектора относительно третьего вектора» (я исхожу из наличия очевидной структуры `vector`):

```
double dotProduct(vector v1, vector v2)
{
    return v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y;
}

double crossProduct(vector v1, vector v2)
{
    return v1.x * v2.y - v1.y * v2.x;
}

bool isInSameHalfPlane(vector v1, vector v2, vector axis)
{
    var p1 = crossProduct(axis, v1);
    var p2 = crossProduct(axis, v2);
    return Math.Sign(p1) * Math.Sign(p2) == 1;
}
```

У нас опять есть два возможных определения того, лежит ли луч между двумя другими.

1. Луч лежит в первом квадранте косоугольной системы координат, задаваемой векторами *v*₁ и *v*₂.

   ```
   // для параллельных векторов результат неопределён
   bool isWithinPositiveQuadrant(vector v1, vector v2, vector w)
   {
       return isInSameHalfPlane(v2, w, v1) &&
              isInSameHalfPlane(v1, w, v2);
   }
   ```
2. Луч лежит в углу, заметающемся положительным поворотом от вектора *v*₁ к вектору *v*₂.

   ```
   bool isDirectedAngle(vector v1, vector v2, vector w)
   {
       var crossSign = Math.Sign(crossproduct(v1, v2))
       if (crossSign > 0)
       {
           // угол от v1 к v2 меньше развёрнутого
           return isInSameHalfPlane(v2, w, v1) &&
                  isInSameHalfPlane(v1, w, v2);
       }
       if (crossSign < 0)
       {
           // угол от v1 к v2 больше развёрнутого
           return !isInSameHalfPlane(v2, w, v1) &&
                  !isInSameHalfPlane(v1, w, v2);
       }
       // здесь вектора параллельны. проверим, сонаправлены ли они
       var areCodirected = dotProduct(v1, v2) > 0;
       if (areCodirected)
       {
           // между сонаправленными векторами ничего не может лежать
           return false;
       }
       else
       {
           // угол между противопололжно направленными векторами - вся полуплоскость
           return crossProduct(v1, w) > 0;
       }
   }
   ```

---

Часть задания, заключающаяся в проверке расстояний, тривиальна.

Comment: Сложно что-то... Можно ж без углов обойтись, вроде?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Не знаю, а как?

Comment: Хотя второй способ и есть без углов.

Comment: Как-то намешать скалярных и векторных произведений. Если вспомню, отвечу :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну так про векторные произведения у меня вся вторая часть ответа. `dotProduct` используется только один раз и случайно :)

Comment: Их там что-то много...

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, наверняка выражения типа `isInSameHalfPlane(v2, w, v1) && isInSameHalfPlane(v1, w, v2)` можно упростить, раскрыв `isInSameHalfPlane`. По существу надо просто подсчитать 3 векторных произведения. Но так, как есть, мне кажется понятнее с геометрической точки зрения. После отладки, да, можно поупрощать.

Comment: Хм.. Что-то я прозевал сначала, что в вопросе дан один вектор и отклоне5ние от него на 35 градусов. Это ж не точки. Хотя можно перевести. Но тут, пожалуй, с углом лучше.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Третий вектор там задан координатами. Так что либо переходить от вектора к углу, либо два угла превращать в вектора. ЗЫ: а, там и в начале тоже точка, сектор задан через середину и отклонение стенок. Ну это уже детали.

Comment: Там же всё от точки (0, 0) по условию? Или я не так понял?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Да, все лучи из нуля. Но они заданы не как 0 ± 35°, а как (направление вектора, заданного координатами _x_, _y_) ± 35°.

Answer (score 1):

Нам надо проверить две вещи:

1. указанная точка лежит в круге,
2. угол между радиус-вектором указанной точки и вектором, задающим сектор, не превышает 35° (по модулю).

Первая проверка тривиальна. Расскажу про вторую.

Если угол не превышает 35° - то его косинус не должен быть меньше `cos 35°`, обратное также верно. Здесь нам сильно помогает симметричность косинуса (`cos -x = cos x`).

Косинус угла между векторами можно найти как их скалярное произведение, поделенное на произведение длин векторов.

В итоге получаем такую вот проверку (здесь (x0, y0) - вектор, который задает сектор, а (x, y) - координаты точки):

```
bool IsInSector(double x0, double y0, double x, double y) {
    var rq0 = x0*x0 + y0*y0;
    var rq = x*x + y*y;
    return rq0 >= rq && (x0*x + y0*y)/Math.Sqrt(rq0*rq) >= Math.Cos(35.0/180.0*Math.PI);
}
```

Comment: Угу. Возможно, эффективнее было бы не брать корень, а отдельно проверить знак, и сравнивать квадраты.

Comment: Да. было бы эффективнее. Но не стал усложнять код.

Answer (score 0):

Формула для тангенса половинного аргумента имеет вид:
tg(fi/2) = sin(fi)/(1+cos(fi)) = y/(x+r) = s, причём в условиях данной задачи **r = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)** (1), x, y - длина вектора (или радиус-вектора точки) и его проекции на оси. При этом угол fi определён с точностью до периода в 360 градусов.

"Заметающий" вектор (u,v) имеет длину **w = sqrt(u^2+v^2)** (2) и исходный угол alpha, для которого tg(alpha/2) = u/(v+w) = t.

Параметры радиус-вектора точки (x,y) определены выше.
При этом в соответствии с формулой для тангенса разности, для тангенса полуразности углов имеем
 tg((fi-alpha) / 2) = tg(fi / 2 - alpha / 2) = (s-t)/(1+st),
 |s - t| <= |1 + st| tg 17.5 deg, или
**|y(v+w) - u(x+r)|<= |(x+r)(u+w)+yu| tg 17,5 deg** (3).

Алгоритм проверки попадания точки (x,y) в 35-градусный сектор вектора (u,v) имеет вид:

1. Вычисляем длину r радиус-вектора точки (x,y) по формуле (1).
2. Вычисляем длину w вектора (u,v) по формуле (2).
3. Сравниваем величины r и w. Если r > w - точка не в секторе.
4. Проверяем условие (3). Если оно выполнено - точка в секторе, иначе - нет

Answer (score -1):

Проверить вхождение в заданный диапазон углов можно так:

```
double AngleDiff(double angle1, double angle2)
{
    return ((((angle1 - angle2) % 360) + 540) % 360) - 180;
}

bool IsInside(double rayAngle, double alpha, double pointAngle)
{
    return (AngleDiff(pointAngle, rayAngle - alpha) > 0 && AngleDiff(pointAngle, rayAngle + alpha) < 0);
}
```

Используется так `var res = IsInside(vectorAngle, 35.0, pointAngle)`

Расстояние между точками можно получить так:

```
double GetDistance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    return Math.Pow(Math.Pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.Pow(y1 - y2, 2), 0.5);
}
```

То есть проверяете - входит ли точка в диапазон углов и расстояние от центра окружности до точки находится в пределах радиуса.

Comment: Чем ваш ответ отличается от ответа VladD?

Comment: А вы что, не видите отличий? Серьёзно?

Comment: У вас меньше информации - и еще вы используете градусы вместо радиан. Ни то, ни другое отличие я бы не назвал положительным.

Comment: Во-первых, где в условии задачи вы увидели радианы? Там несколько раз упоминаются как раз градусы. Смысла использовать радианы здесь нет.

Comment: Во-вторых, что хорошего в той простыне информации? Есть удобный короткий скрипт, выполняющий свою задачу - я его привёл, а также добавил пример использования. Мне что, нужно было тоже написать простыню текста, объясняющую, как выводится эта формула? Не вижу смысла. Если автору вопроса станет это интересно, он спросит и тогда я могу дать подробное описание.

Comment: "Короткий и удобный" скрипт привел я, он еще короче и удобнее вашего (кстати, прочитайте внимательнее вопрос, какие величины нам известны - углов кроме константы в 35 градусов среди них нет). По поводу же радиан - стандартная библиотека языка считает все тригонометрические функции в радианах. Этого не достаточно?

Comment: Когда я начал писать ответ, вашего ответа ещё не было. По поводу радиан - нет, не достаточно. В задаче указаны градусы - они и принимаются как аргументы.

Comment: Это в точности вариант 2 для углов из моего ответа. (Хотя немного менее эффективно, т. к. 2 раза `%`.)

Comment: В точности? По смыслу - примерно. По реализации - нет. Немного менее эффективно? Я бы не был в этом так уверен. Примерно одинаково. Только это совершенно не важно - мы не на конкурсе по высокой производительности.